# Does partial averaging allow moving increments in and out of an expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, levy-processes

Given a Levy process $X$ at different points in time $s$ and $t$, and if I have an expression like this:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_s]]$$

I want to know if I can use partial averaging to say that this is equal to

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t\cdot X_s].$$

Is that correct?

Comment: The first expression is equal to $\mathbb E[X_t]\mathbb E[X_s]$. Can you see why this is **not** equal to $\mathbb E[X_tX_s]$, when $X_t$ is (say) Brownian motion?

Comment: okay, yes I see that!  But can you please tell me why $\mathbb{E}[X_t\mathbb{E}[X_s]]=\mathbb{E}[X_t]\mathbb{E}[X_s]$?  I'm sorry if I'm not seeing obviously.  $X_t$ is not necessarily independent of $X_s$.  The increments are independent but not the specific points.

Comment: For any constant, $k$, $\mathbb E[kX_t]=k\mathbb E[X_t]$. Let $k$ be the constant $E[X_s]$.

Answer (score 2):

let $X$ be a Levy process. Note that $\Bbb E[X_s]$ is then a real number. 
Therefore
$$
\Bbb E[\Bbb E[X_s] \cdot X_t] = \Bbb E[X_s] \cdot \Bbb E[X_t].
$$

As mentioned in the comments, this is (in general) not equal to $\Bbb E[X_s \cdot X_t]$.

Comment: Why does it matterthat it is a real number?

Comment: One of the most basic properties for expectations states that for any real number $c$ we have that $\Bbb E[c\cdot X] = c \cdot \Bbb E[X]$.